# One label with three inputs with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I'd like to know if it's possible to make a form line with jQuerymobile like this prototype bellow.

[image]

I tried to use a layout grid with four columns, like the one bellow, but the Birthday label is bigger than the second column and increases it size.

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
    <label for="idnumber" style="width:50%">
        ID:
    </label>
    <input name="idnumber" id="idnumber" placeholder="(ID Number)" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b">
    <label for="month" style="width:10%">
        Birthday:
    </label>
    <input name="month" id="month" placeholder="MM" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui-block-c" style="width:10%">
    <label for="day">
        &nbsp;
    </label>
    <input name="day" id="day" placeholder="DD" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui-block-d" style="width:30%">
    <label for="year">
        &nbsp;
    </label>
    <input name="year" id="year" placeholder="YYYY" value="" type="text">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Semantically, it would be most appropriate to have "Birthday" be the legend for a fieldset containing the 3 date fields (month/day/year) containing *actual* label text instead of just a space.  You can always set the display for the labels to none if you don't want them visible.

Comment: You are right, but if I make them invisible, the inputs becomes unaligned with other two that have visible labels.

Comment: My recommendation means making all 3 labels (month/day/year) be hidden and only the legend (birthday) visible.  It is up to you to make legend/fieldset look like your other form components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some minutes I posted the question I realized what was the problem. By mistake I put the `style="width:XX%"` inside the labels on the first two fields, instead of putting them inside the block div.

The correct code is the following:

```
<div class="ui-block-a" style="width:40%; margin-right: 10px;">
    <label for="idnumber">
        ID:
    </label>
    <input name="idnumber" id="idnumber" placeholder="(ID Number)" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui-block-b" style="width:15%; margin-right: 5px;">
    <label for="month">
        Birthday:
    </label>
    <input name="month" id="month" placeholder="MM" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui-block-c" style="width:15%; margin-right: 5px;">
    <label for="day">
        &nbsp;
    </label>
    <input name="day" id="day" placeholder="DD" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div class="ui-block-d" style="width:20%">
    <label for="year">
        &nbsp;
    </label>
    <input name="year" id="year" placeholder="YYYY" value="" type="text">
</div>
```

And the correct result is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-grid-a"> 
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <label for="idnumber">
           ID:
        </label>
        <input name="idnumber" id="idnumber" placeholder="(ID Number)" value="" type="text" style="width:90%">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:20%">
            <label for="month">
            Birthday:
            </label>
            <input name="month" id="month" placeholder="MM" value="" type="text" style="width:90%">
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:20%">
            <label for="day">
            &nbsp;
            </label>
            <input name="day" id="day" placeholder="DD" value="" type="text" style="width:90%">
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:60%">
            <label for="year">
            &nbsp;
            </label>
            <input name="year" id="year" placeholder="YYYY" value="" type="text">
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

I think this is more simple. I'm using 2 grid and 3 grid into the second.

Comment: I agree, it's simpler, but the ID field became shifted to the right. I found the solution later. See the answer below. Thanks!